# Sum of two multi-index series with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add two series with multi-indexes of which one can contain NaN values. Just adding both (a + b) doesn't work because some index entries from `a` may not be present in `b` and vice versa.

This is my current approach which fails for index `(b, 50)` as this value should be NaN.

```
In [41]: a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', '1'), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 50), ('b', 5)], names=['x', 'y']))
In [42]: b = pd.Series([4, 5, 6], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', '1'), ('a', 3), ('b', 5)], names=['x', 'y']))
In [43]: c = pd.Series(0, index=a.index.union(b.index))
In [44]: c[a[a.notnull()].index] = a[a.notnull()]
In [45]: c
Out[45]: 
x  y 
a  2     2.0
   3     0.0
   1     1.0
b  1     3.0
   5     0.0
   50    0.0
dtype: float64

In [46]: c[b.index] += b

In [47]: c
Out[47]: 
x  y 
a  2     2.0
   3     5.0
   1     5.0
b  1     3.0
   5     6.0
   50    0.0
dtype: float64

In [48]: c[a.isnull() & b.isnull()] = np.NaN

In [49]: c
Out[49]: 
x  y 
a  2     2.0
   3     5.0
   1     5.0
b  1     3.0
   5     6.0
   50    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC , is this what you need ?

```
a.add(b,fill_value=0)
Out[398]: 
x  y 
a  1     5.0
   2     2.0
b  1     3.0
   50    NaN
   5     6.0
a  3     5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Too easy ;-) Thanks.

Comment: @orange yw~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can align two series first.

```
s1, s2 = a.align(b)
s = s1.fillna(0) + s2.fillna(0) 
s[s1.isna() & s2.isna()] = np.nan

# output of s
x  y 
a  1     5.0
   2     2.0
b  1     3.0
   50    NaN
   5     6.0
a  3     5.0
dtype: float64
```